# Не понятный объект window в Laravel файле resources\ js\ bootstrap.js

Tags: laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

Что делает этот window  в файле

> resources\ js\ bootstrap.js

Является ли он глобальным объектом window в javascript?

В интернете нашел примеры с
кодом `global.instance = require('datepicker')`;

В чем предназначение строк  `global.instance` и `window .jquery`,  имеют ли какое-то значение window, global, что делает строка
`window.Jquery = require('jquery')` ?

Answer (score 0):

В JavaScript все глобальные переменные и функции являются свойствами специального объекта, который называется "глобальный объект" (global object).

В браузере этот объект явно доступен под именем window. Объект window одновременно является глобальным объектом и содержит ряд свойств и методов для работы с окном браузера.

Node.js предоставляет специальный объект global, который предоставляет доступ к глобальным, то есть доступным из каждого модуля приложения, переменным и функциям. Примерным аналогом данного объекта в javascript для браузера является объект window. Все доступные глобальные объекты можно посмотреть в [документации](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html).

> что делает строка window.Jquery = require('jquery') ?

Просто импортирует через `CommonJS` модуль `jquery` и записывает в глобальную переменную Jquery, это делается для удобного доступа с любого участка кода через `window.Jquery` или просто `Jquery`.